# 0xfeeefeee segmentation fault, but simple allocation change?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, fault

I'm implementing a Barnes-Hut simulation program, and have this short snippet of code:

```
BhTree *BhTree::make() {
    return new BhTree();
}
```

The rest of the code (substantial) then works great. The created nodes are **never** deleted during the program lifetime. Using this fact, I wanted to optimize the allocation by using this:

```
vector<BhTree> mSpace;
BhTree *BhTree::make() {
    mSpace.push_back(BhTree());
    return &mSpace[mSpace.size()-1];
}
```

This leads to a dreaded *segmentation fault* in an unrelated section of the code. Interestingly, in a recursive function, where `this` has suddenly been transformed into `0xfeeefeee`, the Microsoft code for heap-freed memory.

Can anyone see off-hand what the problem might be? The vector `mSpace` is **never** accessed elsewhere.

Comment: Where exactly do you define `mSpace`? Static member of `Bhtree`? Global variable?

Comment: you could also return an index, and reference a `BhTree` by its index in `mSpace`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `std::vector` grows it will **reallocate** memory for its contents and invalidate all the previous pointers you handed out.

Comment: Of course! Typical braindead thinking mistake. I'll need to create a large initial buffer then.

Comment: @bombax: You might use a `std::deque` instead as it doesn't invalidate pointers when it grows (from either end).

Comment: Thanks! Though I'm a little concerned about there not being a `reserve` function, as I know approximately how much I need to allocate from the start.

Comment: @bombax `deque` doesn't have it, because it has better (theoretical) time complexity for insertion than `vector`.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a pointer to an object managed by the vector:

```
&mSpace[mSpace.size()-1];
```

The address will become invalid as soon as the vector expands it's internal buffer, and copies the objects to a new location.

You have 3 options:

- Change all your code to pass your objects by value/reference instead of pointers
- Make the vector store `std::shared_ptr<Bhtree>` instead (if your compiler supports C++ 11).
- Make the vector store `Bhtree*` and make sure to `delete` each element

The second variant would look like this:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Bhtree>> mSpace;

BhTree *BhTree::make() {
    mSpace.push_back(std::make_shared<BhTree>());
    return mSpace.back().get();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think the solution I'll go with is to make a sufficiently large initial buffer instead.

Comment: @bombax that would only postpone the problem, and still be vulnerable to undefined behavior. I'd strongly discourage that. Why not go with the 2nd or 3rd option?

Comment: The whole point is to reduce the amount of needed calls to `new`, as I'd rather just allocate a big chunk and use that. But I see your point.

Answer (score 1):

mSpace.push_back() can resize the vector internal array when it determines that it is out of space. When this happens the internal array of the vector becomes invalid and the old pointers to the vector elements are also invalid.